# How to add CSS class to password field using jquery in MVC?

Tags: jquery, html, css, asp.net-mvc

This is my password field

```
@Html.Password("confPwd", null, new { @class = "form-control", @id = "confrimPwd", @placeholder = @Resources.ConfirmPwd , @onchange = "changeBorder()"})
```

I want to add css class to this password field in onblur function
I tried in this way. But its not working. When I apply this to a textfield its working. How can I change border of a Passwordfield?

```
 function changeBorder() {

        if ($("#confrimPwd").val().length != 0) {
            $("#confrimPwd").addClass('successClass');
        }
        else {
            $("#confrimPwd").addClass('errorClass');
        }

    }
```

This is my css classes.

```
    .errorClass {
        border: 1px solid #B94A48;
    }

    .successClass {
        border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
    }
```

Comment: what do you mean by its not working ? are the classes added but only the border doesnt show or arent the classses added ?

Comment: Yes. After addign classes its not display

Comment: Where is your .errorClass and .successClass stored? In the main css file that is available in every view or in some other css file? Have you profiled your code using Firebug or just some browser-tool for insepcting code?

Comment: when you use an element inspector you should see if only the class or the style definitions were applyed too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to handle **onfocusout**

```
@Html.Password("confPwd", null, new { @class = "form-control", @id = "confrimPwd",  @onfocusout = "changeBorder()" })
```

Then when you put your mouse cursor in the password field and left without entering any value, then it will show red border. And when you enter some value and focus out, then you will get grey border.

Also its better you remove CSS class, the way you add them.

```
function changeBorder() {
    if ($("#confrimPwd").val().length != 0) {
        $("#confrimPwd").removeClass('errorClass');
        $("#confrimPwd").addClass('successClass');
    }
    else {
        $("#confrimPwd").removeClass('successClass');
        $("#confrimPwd").addClass('errorClass');
    }

}
```

When you focus out without entering any value -

[image]

When you add some value and focus out -

[image]

PS - For testing purpose, I placed all your styles, Script and Html in single view and tested it. In real case, you might need to check if JQuery is properly referenced or not. Also you have to make sure scripts and styles are properly referenced. Good way to test is to use F12 developer tools of chrome and see if everything is loaded correctly or not.